# Upper Bound of an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If $I_n = \int x^n (1+x)^{0.5} dx$, $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$, where the integral is for $x \in [0, 1]$. By finding a bound on the integrand, which of these is an upper bound on $I_n$?

A. $\frac{1}{n + 1}$;
B. $\frac{1}{2(n + 1)}$;
C. $\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 2}$;
D. $n^n$.

The answer is C, but I couldn't derive the exact expression. Here are some ideas I have right now:

In the interval of $[0, 1]$:

When $n = 0$, $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/2}$, $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-1/2} > 0$, $f''(x) = -\frac{1}{4}(1+x)^{-3/2} < 0$, so $f(x)$ is concave in [0, 1]. Since $f(0) = 1, f(1) = \sqrt{2}$, if I use the trapezoid area to estimate the integral, then it will be $\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx1.207$. This area should be smaller than the actual integral. C gives 1.5, while all the other options are $\leqslant 1$.

When $n=1$, $f(x) = x(1+x)^{1/2}$, $f'(x) = (1+x)^{1/2} + \frac{x}{2}(1+x)^{-1/2} > 0$, $f''(x) = (1+x)^{-1/2}-\frac{1}{4}x(1+x)^{-3/2} > 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, so $f(x)$ is convex in [0, 1]. Take $f(0)=0, f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, and $f(1) = \sqrt{2}$, and calculate the sum of a triangle and a trapezoid, the estimation would be $\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4*2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Similarly, when $n>1$, one can get $f''(x)\geqslant0$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and the estimation: $\frac{1}{2}f(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4*2^{n}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

If I put in some numbers and try it out, C gives the closest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Using Bernoulli’s inequality, $(1+x)^{\frac12}\leqslant 1+\frac12x$.  Now expand and do the integration to get a tighter bound than $C$...

P.S. To exactly get $C$, the simpler estimate $(1+x)^{\frac12}\leqslant 1+x$ suffices.